# Acknowledgement in papers

Tags: publications, paper-submission, acknowledgement

I have helped a scientific(math) author to find a reference and I have corrected several errors in his paper. Should he acknowledges me when he publishes his paper? Will that affect my academic career positively or negatively? And if he doesn't acknowledge me what can I do?

Comment: Under the circumstance that you described, I think the author should acknowledge you, but I also think you shouldn't care much whether he does or not. Acknowledgements are unlikely to help advance your career or status.

Comment: @Andreas Blass Thanks a lot for your reply!

Comment: @Buffy Thank you for editing!

Answer (score 18):

> should he acknowledges me when he publish his paper?

Acknowledgments are discretionary, so they needn't acknowledge you.

> Will that affect my academic career positively or negatively?

Any impact will likely be minimal.

> And if he doesn't acknowledge me what can I do?

You needn't do anything.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But according to APA guide, every person who has contributed to the paper should be mentioned and acknowledged otherwise it will be considered as plagiarism.

Comment: @E.s. Helping-out might not be considered as contributing.

Comment: thanks! So you mean finding a reference that he needed (and that he couldn't find ) and correcting mistakes are not considered as a contribution?

Comment: If you corrected mistakes in his math you should be a coauthour. If you corrected writing you don't require any acknowledgement. You did a favor.

Comment: @CJR If I corrected both? Also, what about the reference provided... is it considered as a contribution?

Comment: @E.s. If you contributed intellectually by correcting the math in the paper in a way that is more than just typography you should be a  coauthor. The other things you have described are favors.

Comment: @CJR thanks! I don't want to be a co-author even if the mistakes were not just typography but someone has told me that in this case the authors should write "The authors would like to acknowledge Mrs. X for her editorial help during the preparation of this manuscript.” ... is this true?

Comment: @CJR I'd say authorship goes beyond _more than just typography_. An intellectual contribution is certainly required, but not sufficient, for me. It's difficult to provide a general quantification though.

Comment: @E.s. I'd say the following is true: The authors _could_ write "The authors would like to acknowledge Mrs. X for her editorial help during the preparation of this manuscript," rather than they _should_ (or _must_).

Comment: The usual standard for co-authorship is to "intellectually contribute" to the material. That means being part of the hypothesis formulation, experimental evaluation, theoretical development, and/or statistical assessment. Finding a reference is not an "intellectual contribution".

Comment: @user2768 Do you mean that if they were grateful to the aid provided, they will mention me in the acknowledgements but if they didn't mention my name it won't be considered as a plagiarism?

Comment: @Wolfgang Bangerth Thanks for your answer! However, I haven't said that I am a co-author :) I have said that they might put my name in the acknowledgements section if they were grateful for the help that I have provided.

Comment: @E.s. -- I was responding to some of the comments above. As for acknowledgments: That's a question of personal preference. Some people (myself included) generally are quite happy to spread praise around, others really just thank those of contributed in very substantial ways. You can't draw any inferences from reading acknowledgments, and everyone knows that -- in other words, nobody is going to think less of you even though you're not listed in a particular paper, even if everyone knows that you contributed to it.

Comment: @Wolfgang Bangerth Thanks for your clarification! Sry i thought u were replying me in your previous comment! No it is not a matter of value (if they think less of me) but in my opinion, since I have helped him in several things so at least (out of respect) he should mention that... but they have told me now there is no rule that says that he should do so (even if the corrected mistakes were not typographic), thus it is not so much important.

Comment: @E.s. Acknowledgements are discretionary, as per my answer.

Comment: As per the answers of everyone, things are more clear. Thank you all for your answers!